# ExprTk, get a list of symbols/variables in expression

Tags: c++, exprtk

I want to get a list of the symbols out of an expression in ExprTk (not the ones I registered, but the ones that are in the expression.
E.g. when the expression is

```
const std::string expression_string = "abs(sin(x)^2+5*y)";
```

I need to get x and y as result as a list/vector or something.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ExprTk readme.txt: **Section 23 - Helpers & Utils** has the following helper free function: **collect_variables**

Usage is as follows:

```
  const std::string expression_string = "abs(sin(x)^2+5*y)";

  std::vector<std::string> variable_list;

  if (exprtk::collect_variables(expression_string, variable_list))
  {
     for (const auto& var : variable_list)
     {
        ...
     }
  }
  else
    printf("An error occurred.");
```

**Note:** If the expression is invalid for any reason **collect_variables** will return false.

Comment: exprtk::collect_variables does not work with following expressions

LANGUAGE in ('SPANISH' + 'ENGLISH' + 'URDU') and PROFICIENCY > 0
101_Courses > 100

Is there a limitation to it?

Comment: @MirzaTalha the expression is malformed, there is a missing operator in: "0 101_Courses"  the error context produced post compile provides all the details you need to detect and resolve the issue.

Comment: "the error context produced post compile provides all the details you need to detect and resolve the issue"

How can I find the errors that caused this function to return false?

Comment: @mihovg93 once the compile method returns a false value, information pertaining about the errors, their nature and locations can be accessed via the error_count and get_error methods. More information and a detailed explanation can be found in the readme.txt in  Section 21 - Compilation Errors.  In short if you also want to know the errors encountered during collect_variables, one can simply implement a similar function that returns the errors.